# bash - executing a command passed as variable using parentheses

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a bash/shell script that basically executes a command from variables.
I've experimented writing it (2) different ways. Enclosing the full command within another variable and the other without.
The one without enclosing in parantheses `()` (not in a variable) will execute, despite some warning messages.

Example 2 will display the warning message and then stops the program. How do I get example 2 to continue to run despite the warning message?

Example 1)

```
export CMD_BIN="$foobar_BASE/sqoop/bin"
export JDBC_CUSTREP="jdbc:postgresql://$2:5432"
export DBOWNER="db_$1"
export DIR_BASE="s4://output01/cust_$1"
export BROWSER="browser/current/part{*} --table browser --fields-terminated-by "\\\001" -- --schema dev_$1"
$CMD_BIN/sqoop export --connect $JDBC_CUSTREP/$DBOWNER --username $DBOWNER --password 'pa$$word' --export-dir $DIR_BASE/$BROWSER
```

Example 2)

```
export foobar_BASE="/home/foobar"
export CMD_BIN="$foobar_BASE/sqoop/bin"
export JDBC_CUSTREP="jdbc:postgresql://$2:5432"
export DBOWNER="db_$1"
export DIR_BASE="s4://output01/cust_$1"

export BROWSER="browser/current/part{*} --table browser --fields-terminated-by '\001' -- --schema dev_$1"
export RUNCMD1 
RUNCMD1=$("$CMD_BIN"/sqoop export --connect "$JDBC_CUSTREP"/"$DBOWNER" --username "$DBOWNER" --password 'pa$$word' --export-dir "$DIR_BASE"/"BROWSER")
```

Comment: The warning message is specific to the sqoop command, basically warns me of using a password on command line. Its not specific to the shell. So, example 1 will execute with that warning

Comment: Why are you exporting `RUNCMD1`?

Comment: Thanks. Would I add `>/dev/null` inside the paren `()`

Comment: You can do it inside or outside, both will work.

Comment: Why did you change the value of `BROWSER` between the two examples?

Comment: The only thing that enclosing a command in `$(...)` does is substitute the output of the command into the command line, instead of writing it to standard output. It doesn't have any effect on the behavior of the program, unless the program tests whether its output is going to a pipe or terminal.

Comment: Why do you think the second one isn't working correctly? What is different about what happens with the second example? Is the "problem" that you don't see the output from the command in the second example?